# What's the difference between using "http://" and just "//" in src or href?

Tags: html, http

I've seen some sites use `//somedomain.com/images/img.jpg` vs using `http://somedomain.com/images/img.jpg` which includes the `http:` as well.

Is there a difference between the two? Is the browser just correcting the missing `http:` and these people are being lazy? Im curious behind the reasoning.

Comment: When you say you've "seen sites" where have you seen them? Is it in print or the name of the link on a web site?

Comment: i mean by viewing their source code. not in a print article or anything like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are already on the site via `http`, it will assume you are talking about `http` and connect to the same server via the same protocol.  Same with `https`.  If you are on `http` and want to go to `https`, you would need to specify the protocol in the `href`.

Comment: so this would be used on sites that can either be viewed on `http` or `https`?

Comment: @chadley - the intention is less for local use, but rather remote use. If `superanalytics.com` offers both HTTP and HTTPS, it might tell you to include its analytics script with the URI `//superanalytics.com/analytics.js`. That way, if you're running HTTP, SuperAnalytics will, too. If you're running HTTPS, SuperAnalytics will, too. And then you don't get those nasty "This is a secure site with unsecure things on it!" warnings.

Comment: thank you for clarifying matchu. that makes perfect sense now that you've pointed out an example.

Comment: Such URLs are known as protocol relative or protocol agnostic URLs.

Answer (score 7):

Not that I've seen it used before, but it is a valid URI-reference. From the grammar:

```
URI-reference = URI | relative-ref

relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

relative-part = "//" authority path-abempty
             | path-absolute
             | path-noscheme
             | path-empty
```

where as an absolute URI is:

```
   URI           = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

For more information, feel free to read the rest of [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Comment: +1. It's excellent! I will use it now everywhere! (At least for the links to the files on the server that hosts static content).

Comment: Note that this means that there's no reason to use two slashes in practice — just one will count as an absolute path.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point. It's valid, but also functional. See @rakuo15's answer.

Comment: Or perhaps this answer encourages research and self-study, by providing a teaser and a link? :)

Comment: @Chuck: it makes sense to use two slashes. Let's say you have http://www.my-dynamic-website.com/some-path/Default.aspx and all static content is hosted at http://my-static-content.com/. Omitting *http* to link to the second domain will save some space in this case.

Comment: this answer is good for proving the use of it is ok but @rakou15's does fully answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: @MainMa: it will save space, but when someone saves a page and access it using the `file` protocol, things will appear to be broken.

Answer (score 3):

Scheme-relative URL's are particularly useful when you're serving a HTTPS website and you would like to share the same static content like stylesheets, images, scripts and so on as from a HTTP site. Hardcoding `http:` in the static content links like `<link href>`, `<script src>`, `<img src>` and so on and viewing the webpage itself over `https:` would cause the average webbrowser to pop a security warning like the following well-known IE security alerts:

[image]

[image]

Serving the "nonsecure" content over a scheme-relative URL would fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

`//somedomain.com/images/img.jpg` is a perfectly valid URI syntax as per [RFC 3986: Section 4.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

It is relative to the current [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme), and therefore it can be very useful when switching between http and https, because you won't need to specify the scheme.

All modern browsers will understand that format, including IE 6.

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen `//somedomain.com/images/img.jpg` and don't think it's legal.

I have seen `/images/img.jpg` which means "use the current domain".  It's helpful if you have several web address (e.g., aaaaa.com & aaaaa.net) pointing to the same site.